# django runserver issue on first start

Tags: django, anaconda

Using Django 3.0 via Pycharm. After starting first time `runserver` I get the following errors. Would anyone know? The project is completely empty. So far only "startproject" and "runserver" was done.

The runserver starts but as soon as I open the link to see in in the browser I get the following meesage?

```
You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
April 02, 2020 - 21:37:53
Django version 3.0.3, using settings 'django_devel_app.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[02/Apr/2020 21:37:56] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16351
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64833)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[02/Apr/2020 21:37:57] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1982
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64834)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\BJS\anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: apply your migrations first

Answer (score 1):

Try this command, and run on a different port

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver 8001
```

Comment: Many thanks, changing the port seems to help. One question, I still get the "Not Found: /favicon.ico", Is there any way I can get rid of this??

Comment: Would u also know why changing the port seems to help?

Comment: Sometimes when some of my programs interfere with the same port, it throws this error and sometime when we cancel the loading page in the browser, this error is thrown. I believe it is this interference

Comment: When you started a project and then somehwere in between runserver with a different port, would that also be possible? Tried that but did not work....

Comment: I set everything up again, then all worked with the old port, now same issues as above again, tried with different port but that does not show anything at all -> I get the original page when u start a project but if I open other pages all are not found...

Comment: "doesnot show anything", did u check the new url, localhost:8001. you have somthing interfering with 8000 port, find out what it is.

Comment: You can run at any port what u want except the basic port, it doesnt matter you are at which stage of your project.

Comment: strange, I get the usual "The install worked successfully! Congratulations!

You are seeing this page because DEBUG=True is in your settings file and you have not configured any URLs." Message

When I then go to /projects which I created I get "Page not found"

Comment: there is something issue with your project configuration check urls.py and wheather it is correctly mapped to views.py

Comment: it looks all ok, If I use the 8000 port I can see the pages if 8001 unfortunately not.

Problem is that on 8000 if I open the pages I get the error message above...